# Is this file operation really "atomic" and "safe"? If not, how can I make it so?

Tags: php, file, io, touch, atomic

I have a function which is supposed to return a unique filename based on the input file path. For example, if the user sends in `C:\meow\bark.txt`, and `C:\meow\bark.txt` already exists, it returns `C:\meow\bark_1.txt`, or `_2` if the `_1` one already exists, and so on.

The crucial part of this function is currently like this:

```
if (!file_exists($candidate_file_path))
{
    if (touch($candidate_file_path))
        return $candidate_file_path;
}
```

That is, if the "candidate" file does not exist, and it can be created ("touched"), then it appears to be safe to return this as a unique file path.

However, I'm not so sure about this. My fear is that some other script, running at the same time, also tries to assign a file with the same name in the same dir at the same time. If script A is currently inside the first if, and is about to "touch" its candidate, and script B has *just* already done that, then script A will still have its `touch()` return `true`, because it just sets the file system metadata for the file, and that's what it returns as "true"/successful. Thus, in such a situation, however unlikely, I will end up with both scripts thinking that they have the same "unique" file path!

This is obviously a recipe for disaster, and eerily similar to my database "transactions" nightmares of the not-so-distant past.

While I'm vaguely aware of the concept of "exclusive file locks", I have to be honest: no matter how much I read about that and tried to use it in the past for other things, I could never figure out how. It would really help me if you could think of some way to make this operation "atomic", or perhaps simply to replace the `touch` call with some other function which I don't even know exists?

I should note that the PHP function `is_writeable` has caused me serious issues in the past, which made me stop using it, according to my own internal comments to myself. If this can be avoided, it would also be good.

Answer (score 1):

This operation is not atomic and not safe.

But there is a way for you to create a file which is guaranteed not to exist by using [`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with the `'x'`(or `'x+'` for added reading) mode as documented in the manual.

Comment: Please do tell me about that way (in the context of my code).

Comment: Just put the specific file path as the first argument and `'x'` as the mode, it will create a new file and return that buffer to you only if the file doesn't already exist, if it does fopen returns false.